# Can I automatically save the current user details using ActiveRecord callbacks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback

I'd like to use ActiveRecord's before_save callback to help me track which users edit which records. For example

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save
   self.edited_by = curent_user.username
  end
  ....
end
```

The problem I'm running into here is that Foo has no idea what current_user is because that's coming from the controller helper.

I could do this all in the controller, I realize. But it'd be nice to just drop this into the before_save callback if I could.

Comment: You might want to consider Cache Sweepers (they have access t the model AND the session (current_user etc)): http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#sweepers

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do this is to make your model richer:

```
class Article
  def edit!(editor)
    self.edited_by = editor.name
    self.save!
  end
end
```

No need to use callbacks.